# Definir tamanho da foto tirada pela a camera do telefone

Tags: android, imagem, android-camera

Gostaria de uma ajuda quanto ao salvamento de imagem no android, tenho uma aplicação que salva a imagem na galeria tudo certinho, so que gostaria de definir um tamanho e qualidade para ela ser enviada ao servidor, se alguem tiver um codigo que possa me ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode diminuir as dimensões de uma imagem usando o [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) passado ao [BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29).

Escreva um método auxiliar para calcular o valor de [BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize):

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // Altura e largura da imagem
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        //Calcula o maior valor de inSampleSize, que é uma potência de 2,
        // que mantém altura e o comprimento maiores do que os valores pedidos.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Escreva um método que leia a foto da galeria e retorne um *Bitmap* com o tamanho pretendido:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(Uri fileUri,
                                                 int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    String path = fileUri.getPath();

    // Primeiro faz o decode com inJustDecodeBounds=true para obter as dimensões
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calcula as novas dimensões
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Faz o decode do bitmap e redimensiona
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
}
```

Use assim:

```
decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(fileUri, 300, 300)
```

<sub>Adaptado da [documentação](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).</sub>

Comment: Obrigado, vou testar aqui na minha aplicação.